# Customise UITableview section in app

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios5

In my app I have 3 categories(sections) and in each category I have 3 items(rows). 
I have implemented it by using grouped style `UITableview`.

But the way it is grouping does not suits my app flow.

How can I customise `UITableview` sections?

I actually want 3 blocks kind of sections and also I should be able to select the whole block not the individual sub-categories(i.e rows). New controller will present when the user selects the whole block. Is their any method like : `-didSelectSectionAtIndexpath`? So that whole action can be performed on the whole section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please elaborate a little on the question? What is it that you want to show once the Sections is touched?? a viewcontroller with the 3 items related to that section or something else??

Comment: I want 3 sections, each section 3 rows and if select the whole section then the next controller will appear. how to do this?

Comment: I would suggest use - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; to make a custom header for your tableview. Keep a button inside this header which would make it clickable. On the other hand do not give any action in didSelectRowForIndex function. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: Yes i got your point and it is going perfectly.. i want to one more thing,this grouped view is not looking good actually the way rows are displayed under each section is not upto the flow of my application.I want each must have a corner radius 0f 3.0 and want to make it much more elegant?

Comment: you want the radius for each row??

Comment: no i want to change the corner radius of each row. so that each row must look a little curvy from corners.

Comment: i guess this is what you are looking for:   cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = .30f;

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom header view as follows and in same way you can set footer as well

**For Header**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];

 /* Create custom view to display section header... */

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
 NSString *string =[list objectAtIndex:section];

 /* Section header is in 0th index... */

[label setText:string];
[view addSubview:label];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:166/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1.0]]; //your background color...
return view;
```

}

**For Footer**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;   // custom view for footer. will be adjusted to default or specified footer height
```

You need to create both views in such a way that it will look same a whole (as per your UI requirement)

Comment: I want 3 sections, each section 3 rows and if select the whole section then the next controller will appear. how to do this?

Comment: @SaurabhGulia -  UI is different for each next controller

Answer (score 1):

There is no `didSelectSectionAtIndexpath` method but you can do some improvisation. you can add a button to the entire header section and then present the new controller on this button click event.

Also call the same new controller on the `didselectrowatindexpath`.

Now set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`  in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This will give the user the impression that he is actually selection the entire block.

You will also have to create the UI smarlty so that the header and row look like one section.